# I will fly from Houston to Madison, ______ Chicago?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request

Suppose I want to go from Houston to Madison and I have bought two flight tickets: one from Houston to Chicago and another from Chicago to Madison.

I wonder how the native speakers of English will explain the role of Chicago in my trip, specifically, I wonder how to complete the sentences like:

> I will fly from Houston to Madison, ______ Chicago.
>
> Chicago is ______ for my trip from Houston to Madison.
>
> I will _____ Chicago when I go from Houston to Madison.

If there are more idiomatic sentences, please let me know.

Comment: Depending on the context, you can use *halt, stop, connecting destination, via...*

Comment: @MaulikV which of the three sentences are you referring to? How do we insert those words properly into the sentences?

Comment: 1st: *via*; 2nd: *a connecting destination*; 3rd: *have a halt in*

Comment: @MaulikV - _stop_ and _connection_ are very common in the US; _halt_ not so much. (In fact, _halt_ might get you a funny look in the US.)

Comment: @J.R. in InE, that's the commonest!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native speaker, but I would say:

> I will fly from Houston to Madison, **via** Chicago.

You could also say

> I will fly from Houston to Madison, **through** Chicago.

Comment: IMO there is a slight difference between the two. *Through* suggests you will just switch planes at the airport, *via* may indicate that you will stay in Chicago for some time. I would not use *via* if I just switched planes.

Comment: @JanDoggen I agree, I'm just giving him options, but you are right.

Comment: @JanDoggen I would agree if I were *traveling* from Houston to Madison but if I am *flying* then *via* would indicate an aircraft change whereas *through* would include stops of any kind, like technical or intermediate stops. But perhaps this gets into frequent flyer jargon.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer already correctly says that *through* is the right word for your first sentence. Here are some suggestions for your other two:

> I will **fly through** Chicago when I go from Houston to Madison
>
> Chicago is **my hub** for my trip from Houston to Madison.
>
> Chicago is **my connecting airport** for my trip from Houston to Madison.

The word *hub* refers to the [*hub-and-spoke system*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hub-and-spoke) employed by most major airlines. As for the phrase *connection airport*, your second flight (from Chicago to Madison) is often called your *connection*, so I might say:

> I heard there is bad weather around Chicago. I hope you don’t miss your **connection**!

Also, the time spent in Chicago is called your **layover** time. So you might answer:

> I know! I have a short **layover**, so I’m a little nervous about that.

One more bit of air travel nomenclature that may be helpful for the leaner:

> I could not get a **direct flight** from Houston to Madison, so I’m flying **through** Chicago.